# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

```
$sql="insert into digifresh_review values('0','$created','$modified','$cus_name','$cus_email','$cus_description','$type')";
if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    header("location: ../digifresh/thankyou.php");
}
else
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Reposted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979341/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by). @mohanraj You can [edit questions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2979256/edit) if you need to add details

Answer (score 2):

One of the easy way to prevent any output to disrupt the method header is to use buffering at the beginning of the page.

Ex.:

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Start buffering //

echo "Some echo";
header('Location: thiswillwork.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue doesn't appear to be in this snippet of code; this happens if you've sent anything to the user before calling the `header()` function. You need to make sure you don't send any data to the client (e.g. `echo`ing something), as that will cause the headers to be sent, which means they can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have white-spaces before your php code.